# Beep on on boot

Tags: boot, kali-linux, grub2

At boot, but before the start of the Kali Linux Live [2020.4] bootloader, two consecutive beeps occur with the text `welcome to grub`; I tried removing the `^G` from `menu.cfg`, but it didn't work, and I couldn't find any other solution online

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this with my device [UEFI], using Rufus to write the 2021.1 ISO to a flash drive:

Open `/boot/grub/config.cfg` and comment out these lines:

```bsh
# insmod play
# play 960 440 1 0 4 440 1
```